# How can I write a fitnesse for a HTML output in Test Driven Development?

Tags: html, asp.net, fitnesse

I have developed an application which produces a HTML output. The HTML output actually contains reports. It has got a few tables. Now I want to write fitnesse for this HTML output. I want to check whether the data in the tables of that HTML are correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

FitNesse is just a test environment, you have to create the connection to your system to actually define how/what to test.

Based on you description I expect you want to test using a browser to see that the generated HTML gives the user the functionality they need. Is that correct?

For those kind of tests Selenium is the most used tool. Multiple plugins/fixtures are available to use Selenium from a FitNesse page (see http://fitnesse.org/PlugIns). Of course I would recommend [my own fixtures](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/wiki) to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks very much @FriedHoeben for your suggestion. Will try in that way.